# PHP mysql auto increment passing BLANK into database

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Hi when I tried to pass a blank value for a primary key in a table, it gave me an error and it won't create/ update.
For example, say id is primary key with auto increment
INSERT INTO client (id, fname, lname) VALUES ('', 'bob', 'smith') won't work.

How do I allow a blank value to pass for a primary key with auto increment?

below is a part of my code:

```
protected static $table_name="client";
protected static $db_fields=array('id', 'fname', 'lname');
public $id;
public $fname;
public $lname;
...more code

public function create() {

    global $database;
    $attributes = $this->sanitized_attributes();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".self::$table_name." (";
    $sql .= join(", ", array_keys($attributes));
    $sql .= ") VALUES ('";
    $sql .= join("', '", array_values($attributes));
    $sql .= "')"; 
    ...more code

}
```

there is a lot more code but I cannot post them all here.
I've tried array_shift() to get rid of the first key which is id but it gave me an error. this whole code is in a class called Client

Comment: You can just ignore `id` column if it is auto increment. Or you can pass `NULL`

Comment: what if I have to have `id` column? is there any way I can pass in a blank and it does not give me an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your id field is primary key and auto increment then no need to pass it in the insert query. Remove the id field and try to insert another fields it will work fine.

Your query should be like :

```
INSERT INTO client (fname, lname) VALUES ('bob', 'smith')
```

In place of :

```
INSERT INTO client (id, fname, lname) VALUES ('', 'bob', 'smith')
```